# Change Google map marker icon size

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I would like to know how to change the size of the map marker icon. I'm unable to get it done after going through the tutorials online!

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(51.124110, -0.073897),
    map: map,
    title: 'Snazzy!',
    icon: 'map_marker.png',
    size: new google.maps.Size(20, 32)
});
```

Comment: What is the default size of markers in pixel?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For those of you who are stuck in similar situations, I got it working with this:

```
var image = {
                    url: 'map_marker.png',
                    scaledSize : new google.maps.Size(50, 50),
                };

                // Let's also add a marker while we're at it
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(51.524110, -0.073897),
                    map: map,
                    title: 'Snazzy!',
                    icon: image
                });
```