# Google Maps API set icon size

Tags: javascript, google-maps, maps

I am having an issue resizing a custom icon/markers on google maps, I want to set the icon size to be 15x15.

You would normally use the below to set the size, but I not sure how to apply this to my custom icon in the fiddle below.

```
scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25)
```

Here is my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ww17amv2/82/

Thanks for any help or suggestions.

Comment: what is the default size of marker in pixel?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need add the size when the icon is set:

```
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
            map: map,
            optimized: false,
            icon: {url:icons[iconCounter], scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(70, 70)},
            title: 'Click to zoom'
        });
```

See: [Change Google map marker icon size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44462283/change-google-map-marker-icon-size)

Comment: Thanks you evitt, exactly what I was after